# Display recent posts with thumbnails with masonry in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-masonry

I am working on a wordpress cms. On a page-template, I need to display recent 10 posts. So I tried to use, `wp_get_recent_posts`, [found here in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts), which I think is an appropriate hook for the purpose.The rest of the code is from my archive.php ( which displays the post-thumbnails in a [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) grid just fine in archive.php). I simply would like to achieve the same thing with the recent posts-thumbnails being on this page-template. Currently, I have this code on a template.

```
<div id="masonry">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item -->
                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <?php
                    $args = array('numberposts' => '10', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id');
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
                    foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
                        if (has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
                            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">';
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'archive_grid');
                            echo '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile;
    endif; ?>
<?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>

</div><!--END #masonry -->

<div id="masonry-new"></div>

<div class="post-navigation clearfix"><!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
<?php dt_pagination(); ?>
</div><!--END .post-navigation -->
```

**ISSUE** : This code returns just a single thumbnail from the most recent posts. I have no clue what is wrong with the loop. The other weird thing to notice is when I `var_dump` the `$recent_posts` it returns other text-contents of the posts just fine. If you need to know this, I have my setting as `setting->reading->Blog pages show at most->20 posts`.

Comment: what's the count of the $recent_posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to have two loops if I understood correct what you want to do. Also `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'` isn't necessary. I suppose is just the thumbnail id and not a meta key created by you.

You could achieve what you want like that:

```
<div id="masonry">
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false );

    $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($recent_posts as $key=>$post): setup_postdata( $post ); {
    ?>
                <div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item -->
                    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                        <?php


                            if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {
                                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">';
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'archive_grid');
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php } ?> //end of foreach loop
    <?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>

    </div><!--END #masonry -->

    <div id="masonry-new"></div>

    <div class="post-navigation clearfix"><!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
    <?php dt_pagination(); ?>
    </div><!--END .post-navigation -->
```

But this way you have to fix the pagination your self.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that get_posts doesn't work with pagination.

```
<div id="masonry">
<?php

    $paged = 1;
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'paged'        =>  $paged,
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );  

    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    ?>
                <div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item -->
                    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                        <?php


                            if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {
                                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">';
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'archive_grid');
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                        ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php  endwhile; ?> //end while loop
    <?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>

    </div><!--END #masonry -->

    <div id="masonry-new"></div>

    <div class="post-navigation clearfix"><!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
    <?php dt_pagination(); ?>
    </div><!--END .post-navigation -->
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

If the second solution doens't work you have to provide the dt_pagination() function to see how is working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution worked. Is there a way to fix the pagination. Currently it does not seem to paginate.

Comment: I update my solution. Haven't test it but it should work now with pagination.

Comment: this one does not work. It displays about 37 posts in no particular order and also their text content (totally unwanted). The pagination seems to work in this one though.

Comment: Their text content? Why ? We didn't call the text anywhere. Maybe a plugin or the theme alter the wp_query. It should work. Would you mind post the dt_pagination function ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you dont need two loops. Try new wp query instead of wp_get_recent_posts. here is an example for you.

```
  <div id="masonry">
      <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => '10' ); 
      $loop = new WP_Query($args); if( $loop->have_posts() ):
      while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); global $post;  ?>

      <div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item -->
                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                    <?php


                        if (has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {
                            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">';
                            echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'archive_grid');
                            echo '</a>';
                        }
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_Query(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>


  </div><!--END #masonry -->
```

Comment: This query example displays around 36 posts in no particular order.

Comment: @gurung  are you sure ? posts number is limited to 10. by default it's odering by ASC

Comment: Yes I am sure. But as of now the above solution seems to work. So, it would be great if you can help with pagination. I appreciate your help. thanks.